# List conversion into list containing rules

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I convert the two lists:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3};
list2 = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
```

into a list:

```
{1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two", 3 -> "Three"}
```

Comment: `Thread[list1 -> list2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MapThread[Rule,{list1 ,list2}]
```